# Stuck on AngularJS Filter

Tags: angularjs

I have the below custom filter that will truncate text after a certain number of characters:

```
test.app.filter('cut', function () {
return function (value, wordwise, max, tail) {
    if (!value) return '';

    max = parseInt(max, 10);
    if (!max) return value;
    if (value.length <= max) return value;

    value = value.substr(0, max);
    if (wordwise) {
        var lastspace = value.lastIndexOf(' ');
        if (lastspace != -1) {
            value = value.substr(0, lastspace);
        }
    }

    return value + (tail || ' …');
};
});
```

If I apply it to ng-options, it does not work - the options in the drop down disappear:

```
<select name="country" class="form-control" ng-options="country.value as country.label for country in countries | cut:true:20:' ...'" ng-model="address.Country" placeholder="{{'Country' | r | xlat}}" ng-required="address.IsCustEditable != false" ng-disabled="address.IsCustEditable == false" />
```

It works great though in other elements, such as this:

```
  <strong>{{v.ExternalID | cut:true:20:' ...'}}</strong>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the an object to the filter when it expects a string.

That's why when you do :

```
<strong>{{v.ExternalID | cut:true:20:' ...'}}</strong>
```

It works. If you did this :

```
<strong>{{v | cut:true:20:' ...'}}</strong>
```

You would have a similar issue.

You could rewrite the filter to take and object, like this :

```
test.app.filter('cut', function () {
return function (obj, wordwise, max, tail) {

    var value = obj.label || obj ;

    if (!value) return '';

    max = parseInt(max, 10);
    if (!max) return value;
    if (value.length <= max) return value;

    value = value.substr(0, max);
    if (wordwise) {
        var lastspace = value.lastIndexOf(' ');
        if (lastspace != -1) {
            value = value.substr(0, lastspace);
        }
    }

    return value + (tail || ' …');
};
});
```

But that becomes a bit messy if the filter is expected to handle multiple object structures.

You could also rewrite the ng-options statement. I always find the ng-options dsl a bit awkward. Here are a couple ways I think you could write this, but it might take some tinkering to get it correct. The idea remains the same though, you need to get the string to the filter, not the object :

```
country.value as country.label for country in countries | cut:country.label:true:20:' ...'
```

Or like this

```
country.value as (country.label | cut:true:20:' ...') for country in countries
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing. I appreciate the thorough response!